# global variables in javascript inline styling

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm giving a try to [glamor](https://github.com/threepointone/glamor) pushed by [next.js](https://github.com/zeit/next.js). I'm trying to convert some CSS files to glamor syntax.

Currently I use CSS3 variables to define some common rules and `calc` to adapt thoses variables to my components context

```
#variables.css
:root {
--gutter: 1rem;
}

#myComponent.css
.myComponent {
margin:calc(var(--gutter) / 2)
}
```

I'm struggling to find a good way to translate that in glamor API.

So far I do things like that :

```
#variables.js
export const gutter = 1;

#myComponent.js`
import {gutter} from 'variables.js';
const style = css({
  margin:(gutter * 2) + 'rem'
});
```

But I'm not satisfied with the `+'rem'` part and the lack of unit in `gutter` definition.

Am I doing it wrong ? is there a better way ?

Comment: pointlessly converting css to javascript code which will convert it back to css could be considered "wrong"

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. I admit it looks weird, but I don't see any other way to specify css units in glamor based on js variables. Are you suggessting I should stick to CSS and ignore nextjs recommandation ?

Comment: Maybe i just dont undrestand. (Answering questions on my phone while driving) what is the purpose of using javascript to compile your css?

Comment: Have you looked into [glamor's `vars`](https://github.com/threepointone/glamor/blob/master/examples/vars.js)?

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. you mean what's the purpose of CSS-in-JS ? In my case my need is drived by next.js recommandation. But in general the whole point of it is explained here : https://vimeo.com/116209150 originally (basically : isolation, removing selectors...) In my case I also have issues with css variables not available in media queries. drive safe.

Comment: @FabianSchultz I haven't. But it seems like it won't solve my issue with units and calc.